# HowTo: Tune numpy dependencies on google colab?

Tags: python, numpy, theano, google-colaboratory, blas

I recently pushed my ML training proccess in the cloud since its 2019 right ?
I use google collab as the title suggests.

Now I have seen rough performance variations between my local runtime and the one in the cloud which was to expect but it was odd:

My local CPU @ 1.1 GHZ was outperforming the CPU @ 2.3 GHZ in colab.
Some further research later I found some ressources discussing numpy and scipy dependencies like BLAS and ATLAS:

- [some blog](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2018/04/15/)
- [someother blog](http://blog.nguyenvq.com/blog/2014/11/10/optimized-r-and-python-standard-blas-vs-atlas-vs-openblas-vs-mkl/)
- [github issue](https://github.com/tmolteno/necpp/issues/18)

and sure enough I had different versions locally than I had in the cloud.

Now the question arises how do I pick the right/fastest configuration for my project?

I started benchmarking on one configuration I got running and was surprised once again! Colab offers 2 hardware accelerators GPU and TPU

> NONE (hh:mm:ss.ms) : 0:03:54.237129
>
> GPU  (hh:mm:ss.ms) : 0:03:47.573604
>
> TPU  (hh:mm:ss.ms) : 0:03:52.045764

I would have thought that TPU would be better than GPU and at that point I realized that I really dont know enough and need help ^^

Some further thoughts:

-I guess since colab is using intel cpus(lscpu said intel) and gpus(?) the intel MKL could be worth a look but I didnt get in running and that would be a whole nother post

```
numpy.__config__.show()
```

provides some insight on what dependencies are curently used by numpy:[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/v0x3sTUf)

I built libgpuarray from source with the following set of commands on an ext4:

```
!git clone https://github.com/Theano/libgpuarray.git
%cd libgpuarray
!mkdir Build
%cd Build
!cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
!make
!make install
%cd ..
!python setup.py build
!python setup.py install
```

openBLAS:

```
!sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev
```

and then some pip stuff:

```
!pip install pydot
!pip install pygame
!pip install mido
!pip install keras
```

and finally I run my project with:

```
!THEANO_FLAGS=blas.ldflags="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas" python2.7 train.py
```

So what are steps to improve the speed of my training ?
Please dont hesitate to ask for more info if you need it!

Thanks for reading